# How to obtain a control using its name in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have a TextBox named `txtCod1` and I want to obtain its text when I click a button, but I want to get their properties using a variable to reference it.

```
Private Sub btnAceptar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAceptar.Click

    Dim txtDato As TextBox
    txtDato = Me.Controls.Item("txtCod1")
    MsgBox(txtDato.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)

End Sub
```

When I execute this code, it returns an error.

Comment: If the `textCod1` is already on the form you don't need to do anything special to reference it. E.g. `txtCod1.Text` should be working just fine.

Comment: Yes, it exist in the form.

Comment: So go ahead and drop the line `txtDato = ...`. Next,in the `MsgBox(` use `txtCod1.Text` inteas of `txtDato.text`...

Comment: `MsgBox(txtCod1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)` should work

Comment: The trouble is I don't want to obtain his value at this way, because I have more controls using a similar name... And I want to make a loop to obtaint their Text.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch, Yes, it works... But I would like to obtain his value using a variable to reference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I found the solution...
I tried with this and works:

```
If Me.Controls.Find("txtCod1", True).Count = 1 Then
    Dim b As TextBox = Me.Controls.Find("txtCod1", True)(0)
    MsgBox(b.Text)
End If
```

Comment: Don't force it loop twice! That's a waste of resources and processing power. Put the returned collection in a variable instead: `Dim foundControls = Me.Controls.Find("txtCod1", True)` and then: `If foundControls.Count > 0 Then` and: `Dim b As TextBox = DirectCast(foundControls(0), TextBox)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter out the controls you need.
The quickest solution would be to use Linq.
So import `System.Link` and do:

```
    Dim textBoxes = Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(c) c.Name.StartsWith("txtCod"))

    For Each tb In textBoxes
        MsgBox(tb.Text)
    Next
```

The [OfType(Of...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.1) method returns only the elements that can be cast to the type you've specified.

## EDIT

You need to tweak the name constraint or remove the `.Where(...)` call if there are no other than `txtCod...` textboxes on the form.
You can play with `c.Name.Contains("bla")` if you need to find a portion of the name which is not in the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, but it don't works... I tried it, but don't show any message.