# I have a textbox control name in a file that i want to read in and set the value of that textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So i want to assign the values to the corresponding textbox listed in the file.
Is this possible?

```
txtLvlMultiplier_S_00   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_15   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_14   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_13   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_12   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_11   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_10   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_09   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_08   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_07   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_06   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_05   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_04   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_01   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_03   1
txtLvlMultiplier_S_02   1.2
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How To Get Control Property by "String Name"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name), [How to obtain a control using its name in Visual Basic .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47243351/8967612)

Comment: It would be better to store the data as JSON, read that into an object and then bind that object to your UI.